# want to take a database value in a variable

Tags: mysql, sql, shell

i need to take a value from database in a variable in shell programming. i am using below command. but getting error.

```
applicant= `mysql -uroot -p123456 -e 'SELECT applicant FROM 
    leave where status="Applied" and applying_date= curdate() 
    order by applying_date' comviva|tail -1`;
```

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for 
the right syntax to use near 'leave where status="Applied" and 
applying_date= curdate() order by applying_date' at line 1
```

Comment: I dont know about shell programming much but I think you should need to specify database name in your query. so try databasename.leave in your query

Comment: @RonakShah The database name os specified in the argument to `mysql`, it's `comviva`.

Comment: @barmar Oh ok.. Actually don't know much about shell programming. so just guessing. thank you for sharing your knowledge

Comment: It has nothing to do with shell programming, it's just the syntax of that specific command. Read its documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LEAVE` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), you need to put it in backticks. Also, there must not be a space after `=` in the variable assignment.

```
applicant=$(mysql -uroot -p123456 -e 'SELECT applicant FROM 
    `leave` where status="Applied" and applying_date= curdate() 
    order by applying_date' comviva|tail -1);
```

Comment: thanks for answer. can i use this value that stored in applicant variable.

Comment: It's an ordinary variable, you can use it just like any other shell variable.

Comment: I wonder why you need the `ORDER BY` clause. All the records returned by the query have the same `applying_date`.